# Function Array Elements Sum

Tags: c++, c, function

The below code will print the sum of elements in the array passed as the argument.Define the method printArrayElementsSum

```
int printArrayElementsSum(long int arr[],int N)
{
    long int sum=0;
    long int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    sum+=arr[i];
    printf("%lld",sum);
    
    return sum;
    
    
}
int main()
{
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int arr[N], index;
    for(index=0; index < N; index++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[index]);
    }
    printArrayElementsSum(arr,N);
    return 0;
}
```

If the input is

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

i need the output as `15` But the above code giving me wrong answer What mistake i have done please rectify it And the arr element is >100000

Comment: Here's a hint: you are not using your `N` parameter

Comment: *What mistake I have done please rectify it*
-Debugging your own code is part and parcel of learning how to write programs. Just writing a program, seeing that it doesn't produce the correct results, and then asking someone else (StackOverflow members in this case) to debug your code is not how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Would you mind selecting *one of * C and C++, which are different languages?

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::accumulate` for summing sequences, whereas C doesn't.  Please adjust your tags accordingly.